# I am trying to calculate the monthly percentage but its giving me wrong answer always

Tags: percentage, tibco, spotfire

this is my data.

MOnth     Key Resource

Jan         Yes
Jan         Yes
Jan         Yes 
Jan         No
Jan         No

I wanted to calculate the percentage of key resources in the month of Jan. So what i did is first i calculated how many key resources are there calculation (case when [Key Resource]  = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end. Then to calculate the monthly key resource percentage i tried a calculation = sum(key resources) / count(Key Resource). But this is not giving me the correct answer. Please help

Answer (score 2):

If you just insert a calculated column you run into problems. Spotfire will calculate this record for record.

I created the column [Calc] (via insert calculated column): `(case when [Key] = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end)`

the calculation Sum([Calc]) / Count([Key]) will return the correct values in most visualizations when you enter this as a custom expression. Just try it on a bar chart, with Month on the categorical axis.

If you want to have the calculation in the standard table, you need to insert a calculated column with the following syntax: `Sum([Calc]) over ([Month]) / Count([Key]) over ([Month])`. This breaks your calculation so it calculates per month.

I used the following data, calc and calculation are as mentioned above:

```
Month Key Calc Calculation
Jan Yes 1 0.6
Jan Yes 1 0.6
Jan Yes 1 0.6
Jan No 0 0.6
Jan No 0 0.6
Feb Yes 1 0.25
Feb No 0 0.25
Feb No 0 0.25
Feb No 0 0.25
```

Comment: just a tip that you can also put `CASE` and `IF` statements inside of aggregate functions: `Sum(if(Upper([Key]) = "YES", 1, 0))` is 100% valid, and comes in handy when you have lots of small, one-off calculations that don't really require a new column. the downside of this approach is that marking can behave strangely because Spotfire evaluates ALL records as part of the Sum(); not just records that evaluate to 1.

Comment: @niko, I know, but to keep the overview in the example I thought it prudent to keep everything separate, especially with over functions involved.